# Проверка всех текстбоксов на пустоту и их очищение

Tags: c#, исключения, textbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как проверить все разом на введенные данные и разом отчистить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Цикл foreach по свойству Controls. Придется отделять текстбоксы от других контролов. НО если разместить их в одном родительском контроле, то эту проблему легко решить.

2) Цикл for по свойству Controls[$"textBox{i}"], если имена боксов textBoxN, где N - число.

3) Наконец, добавить их в массив, еще в конструкторе формы, и легко работать с массивом циклами.

Примерно так, пишу по памяти

```
int err=0;
foreach (Control c in Controls) {
   if (c is TextBox) {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((c as TextBox).Text)) err++;
   }
}
if (err > 0) 
   MessageBox.Show($"Неправильно заполнены поля ({err})");
else
   // необходимые действия
```

Про очистку немного не понял, но точно так же в цикле вызывайте .Clear() или приравниваете свойство Text к пустой строке.

Comment: Попробую. Спасибо

Comment: пример не заработал =(

Comment: @ne0n что у вас не работает ? продублирую ответ, вы не пишите не работает, а пишите как есть не понял , не сделал правильно не стесняйтесь, здесь никто богом не родился, всё даётся в тяжёлом учении на протяжении жизни . Пример 100% рабочий.

Comment: @DigitalCore ну я пример запихал в кнопку, после else написал нужный код. Не заполнял текстбоксы а действие из else выполнилось. MessageBox не появился

Comment: @ne0n код нужно не пихать в кнопку, а немного осмыслить его перед использованием.

Comment: через Controls.OfType<TextBox>() получается чуть красивее

Comment: @PashaPash я сначала так и начал писать, но потом решил всё-же убедить ТС в том, что ответ на его вопрос дан верно, и код рабочий.  Согласен красивее и код короче .

Comment: @PashaPash можешь набросать ) буду благодарен

Comment: @ne0n вам уже два участника набросали готовые решения. если они вам не подходят - напишите, чем именно.

Comment: @ne0n из догадок - вам нужно идти не по form.Controls, а по groupBox.Controls - у вас текстбоксы лежат не на форме. в остальном - код должен работать.

Comment: @PashaPash ладно. Спасибо за ответы. Завтра уже буду думать

Answer (score 3):

**Дублирую метод приведённый Uranus немного подредактированный.**

```csharp
private void contolEmptyCount()
{
    int cc = 0;
    foreach (var c in Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((c as TextBox).Text))
                (c as TextBox).Text = "control = " + cc++;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(cc.ToString());
}
```

**И не имеют значения (имена) `Name` контролов.**

**Выведем имена контролов с пустым полем `Text`**

```csarp
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var c in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
                c.Text = "Control Name = " + c.Name;
    }
```